# Named giant animal

Tags: dwarf-fortress

My hunter got killed by Tollissedil Giant Mantis and i am wondering why this mantis is named? It is not a forgotten beast and after sending my military at it my dwarfs refuse to bring him to the slaughter house, is this because he is named? Might it be a pet from a invader?

Comment: Is the corpse outside? If your dwarves are set to collect refuse from outside, you should be able to retrieve what's left of its corpse.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wild animals get named by a few means; a common one aside from being a pet is if they manage to kill enough enemies. You can check it in history mode for yourself - quit the game, copy the last save somewhere, restart and abandon the fort, and restart the world in the history viewing mode. Tolissedil will be in there, somewhere, with all of his exploits and killings. You can restore your old save with your functioning fort afterwards.

"Tolissedil" is a Dwarven name ("tolis" = top, "sedil" = angel), so chances are it only got that name from the killing of your hunter.

See also: [Animal and Megabeast names on DF wiki](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2012:Name#Animal_and_Megabeast_Names)

Answer (score 7):

Besides being adopted as a owner animals can also be [given names](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2012:Name#Animal_and_Megabeast_Names) during world gen if they become an enemy of a civilization or if they have any notable kills.

They should, under normal circumstances, be [butcherable](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2012:Giant_mantis) so I don't know why that happened.
It could be because the corpse is to damaged.

Comment: The reason why it isn't butcherable is because the OP sent the military to kill it, which prevents butchering. Only hunters kill and butcher other lifeforms.

Comment: Ooh right, I forgot about that. It's been to long since I played Dwarf Fortress :(

Comment: @DoktoroReichard I think your comment directly answers the part of the question about butchering.

Comment: @DoktoroReichard: I'm not at all sure that's true.

Comment: @WillihamTotland from the [Butcher](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2012:Butcher) page of the DFWiki: "If the hunter kills more than one creature on a single hunting trip the rest of the corpses will just be left on the ground; **the same is true for creatures killed by traps or the military**. To get those corpse butchered you need to put a refuse stockpile next to the butchery and set it to only accept corpses, and then set standing orders to gather outside refuse.".

Comment: @DoktoroReichard: My point exactly. The manner of death doesn't prevent butchering, it just means a hunter won't drop it in the butchery.

Comment: At any rate, the information present here *should* then be updated to any answer that deems it fit.

Comment: Moving it to a refuse pile actually solved the butchering issue. Strangely because the mantis got killed about 10 tiles next to it. My bearded fella's are now enjoying some Asian delicacy, giant mantis brain bisque's.